# multiple setInterval timers on node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

My app is a game where a user has 30 mins to finish....node backend

Each time a user starts a game then a setInterval function is triggered server side....once 30mins is counted down then I clearInterval.

How do I make sure that each setInterval is unique to the particular user and the setInterval variable is not overwritten each time a new user starts a game? (or all setInterval's are cleared each time I clear).
Seems like I might need to create a unique "interval" variable for each new user that starts game??

Below code is triggered each time a new user starts a game

```
 let secondsLeft = 300000;
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        secondsLeft -= 1000;

        if (secondsLeft === 0) {
          console.log("now exit");
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 10000);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: If it was me, I would record start time of game and calculate end time of game and save those data corresponding to user id rather than using `setInterval` on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda) for a pretty big strategy game backend which offers the benefit of persistence if the node app crashes etc.

We incorporated the user id into the job name and would then schedule the job, along with data to process, to run at a determined time specifying a handler to execute.

The handler would then run the job and perform the relevant tasks.

```
// create a unique jobname
const jobName = `${player.id}|${constants.events.game.createBuilding}`;
// define a job to run with handler
services.scheduler.define(jobName, checkCreateBuildingComplete);
// schedule it to run and pass the data 
services.scheduler.schedule(at.toISOString(), jobName, {
   id: id,
   instance: instance,
   started: when
});
```

Worked pretty well and offered decent protection against crashes. Maybe worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

First: Concurrent Intervals and Timers are not the best design approach in JS, it is better to use one global timer and a list of objects storing the start, end, userid etc and update these in a loop.

Anyway. To have your interval id bound to a certain scope, you can use a Promise like so:

```
const createTimer = (duration, userid) => new Promise(res => {
  const start = new Date().getTime();

  let iid;

  (function loop () {
    const 
      now = new Date().getTime(),
      delta = now - start
    ;
    //elapsed
    if (delta >= duration) {
      clearTimeout(iid);
      res(userid);
    //try again later
    } else {
      iid = setTimeout(loop, 100)
    }
  })();
});
```

This way each timer will run »on its own«. I used `setTimeout` here since that wont requeue `loop` before it did everything it had to. It should work with `setInterval` as well and look like that:

```
const runTimer = (duration, userid, ontick) => new Promise(res => {
  const 
    start = new Date().getTime(),
    iid = setInterval(
      () => {
        const delta = new Date().getTime() - start;

        if (delta < duration) {
        //if you want to trigger something each time
        ontick(delta, userid);

        } else {
          clearInterval(iid);
          res(userid);
        }


      }, 500)
  ;

});
```

You do not even need a promise, a simple function will do as well, but then you have to build some solution for triggering stuff when the timer is elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Chev and @philipp  these are both good answers.

I was also made aware of a technique where you use an array for the setInterval variable.....this would make my code as follows;

```
 let intervals = []
 let secondsLeft = 300000;
      intervals['i'+userId] = setInterval(() => {
        secondsLeft -= 1000;

        if (secondsLeft === 0) {
          console.log("now exit");
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 10000);
```

Does anyone else foresee this working?.

UPDATE 6.56pm PST.....it works!!

Comment: You can simply keep an object if the ID is suitable, or array of reference to the intervals like intervals[userID] = setInterval(..) etc. It's not a robust solution as servers restart/crash and then all your players are in trouble!